# localize a picturebox image from a resource from a satellite library

Tags: c#, localization, resources, picturebox, resx

I am attempting to write a small program that uses localized resources that depend on the language and culture. You can view a video explanation [here](http://youtu.be/d4bvo5oHi70).

My two questions are

1. How can I (from the IDE/Visual Studio) access resources from a satellite DLL
2. Specifically, how can I access an image for a pictureBox control.

Here are the two Projects:

[image]

One is a library and one is a windows form project. I want to reference the resx files from Form1. If this is not the correct way to use this, please explain how I should be creating my satellite DLL.

Here is how I want the Form to look in American Culture:

[image]

and here is how I want it to look in Australian Culture:

[image]

Comment: Start by reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xdxwwkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please check this page:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.80).aspx
   It is about how to localize a string and from which you will know we use different resource file for different language version.
   Here is the description of it from that page:
   "In general, you should use forms-based resources for all resources specific to a form in your Windows Forms application. You should use project resources for all non-forms-based user interface strings and images, such as error messages."
2. Here is way and code about image:
   [Localization of image resources in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387699/localization-image-resources-in-winforms)
   and a step by step solution here:
   [Proper localization of a WinForms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251225/proper-localization-of-a-winforms-application)

I've just completed a C# .Net 3.5 project with a similar problem. We were writing WinForms plugin for an existing multi-lingual application with 8 languages (including English).
This is how we did it:
Create all our forms and UI in the default language, English.
Put all our internal strings in a resource file (stuff not tied directly to a form like custom error messages and dialog box titles etc)
Once we had completed most of the work and testing we localised it.
Each form already had a .resx file but this was empty. We set the property 'Localizable' to true, the .resx file was filled with things like button sizes & strings.
For each of the other languages, we changed the 'Language' property on the form. We chose the basic version of each language eg: 'Spanish' instead of 'Spanish (Chile)' etc. so that it would work for every 'Spanish' dialect, I think.
Then we went through each control, translated its text and resized, if needed. This created a .resx per language and form combination.
We were then left with, for 8 languages, 8 .resx for each form and 8 .resx for the general strings. When compiled the output folder had the .dll we were creating and then a sub folder for each language with a .resources.dll in it.